# 307 response on azure server while big amount of requests

Tags: azure, .net-core, httpresponse, asp.net-core-3.1

I am interested about some strange behavior of my .net core 3.1 server. I made some benchmarks on loader.io '[image]

When my server gets a lot of requests per second. I get the 307 response instead of 200 (because it is simple HTTP GET request, so I should get 200).

Request: "host/api/..." is the simplest get.
"Location" in header in response is the same url as was requested, I mean when "X" url was called, "X" url was included in Location in response.
This is sample of my Log from azure

> {"RequestScheme":"http","AddressIp":"34.204.191.83","ResponseHeader":"[Location, https://onlinedoctor.azurewebsites.net/api/doctor/getdoctors]","RequestMethod":"GET","RequestPath":"/api/doctor/getdoctors","StatusCode":307,"Elapsed":0.0974,"SourceContext":"Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware","RequestId":"0HM4D65VS83G8:00000001","SpanId":"|82de96cf-4cd9d83596f676e5.","TraceId":"82de96cf-4cd9d83596f676e5","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HM4D65VS83G8","MachineName":"RD501AC5A97F1B","ProcessId":21264,"ThreadId":61}

Is it some prebulid middleware in .net core to maintain the server traffic or how to set your own rules?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 307 is Temporary redirect.

It may be that when the load is too high for your service, Azure is trying to redirect the request to a different instance of the service.

You need to implement security on your site. Using the url in the question it is possible to get a list of all doctors in your system.

https://onlinedoctor.azurewebsites.net/api/doctor/getdoctors

Comment: Yeap I made it public to test the request